# How to generate a [FIN] flag whwn I have sent a string using TCPIP connection with [FIN,PSH,ACK]

Tags: .net, tcp

I am trying to emulate a client program that talks to an existing server. I have used wireshark and can see the messages to and fro.
The client program - connects and send a string

```
9 0 0 99 3 0 CR LF 
CLIENT SEND
0.001157    192.168.0.210   192.168.0.197   TCP 69  61517 → 22223 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=131328 Len=15
```

then an empty  string just

```
CR LF
0.001232    192.168.0.210   192.168.0.197   TCP 56  61517 → 22223 [FIN, PSH, ACK] Seq=16 Ack=1 Win=131328 Len=2
```

the server responds with an ACK and a return text message , followed by the CR LF

```
SERVER RESPONSE
0.002383    192.168.0.197   192.168.0.210   TCP 60  22223 → 61517 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=19 Win=525568 Len=0
0.004112    192.168.0.197   192.168.0.210   TCP 66  22223 → 61517 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=19 Win=525568 Len=12
0.004113    192.168.0.197   192.168.0.210   TCP 60  22223 → 61517 [FIN, PSH, ACK] Seq=13 Ack=19 Win=525568 Len=2
```

When I try to emulate the client -  everything seem the same EXCEPT I do not get a  [FIN, PSH, ACK] just a [PSH,ACK] and the server doesn't respond.
In my experiments I found that if I closed the the stream after the write to the server , I can see on wireshark that the response is send (but now the link is closed so I can't get it)
Does anyone know how to generate the [FIN,PSH,ACK] whilst leaving the connection alive ??

MY SEND MESSAGE ROUTINE

```
Public Async Sub SendMessage(ByVal msg As String) 'Handles sendButton.Click
    Try

        If client IsNot Nothing AndAlso client.Connected Then

            Dim stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream
            Dim myBytes2() As Byte = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(msg)
            Try
                Await stream.WriteAsync(myBytes2, 0, myBytes2.Length)
                'stream.Close()
            Catch ioex As System.IO.IOException
                DisplayLog("Server terminated connection")
            Catch odex As ObjectDisposedException
                DisplayLog("client terminated connection")
            Catch er As Exception
                DisplayLog("ERROR Module:{" & GetModuleName(er) & "}" & Information.Err().Number & " Mess:" & er.Message)
            End Try
        End If
    Catch er As Exception
        DisplayLog("ERROR Module:{" & GetModuleName(er) & "}" & Information.Err().Number & " Mess:" & er.Message)
    End Try


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having the wrong expectations of how TCP works. The FIN is not the end of some message but the end of the full connection. Therefore it is send when you close the stream, but not after a message.

TCP does not provide any kind of message semantics at all, it is only a byte stream. If you need message semantics you cannot add these to TCP by sending a FIN at arbitrary and multiple times within an existing connection, but you have to add these message semantics on top of the TCP by stream. Typical approaches are to prefix the message with a length or to have some kind of end-of-message marker (like CR LF in text based protocols).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Steffen,
Yes indeed I do not completely understand the TCP . I have however written many clients for TCP servers and have not come across this particular scenario.
In monitoring the connection with Wireshark the only thing that i can see is different from my client to the existing client is that after the string is send to the server, with the [PSH,ACK] the [FIN,PSH,ACK] is send with a terminating string of CR,LF.
Without this FIN (or connection closed) the server will not send the response...
Confused...
Paul

Comment: @Paul: What you describe is unusual in communication but not impossible: the client does a one-sided shutdown of the connection, i.e. it signals that it will no longer send any data inside the connection but still can receive data. To achieve this you need to use [Shutdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.shutdown?view=netcore-3.1) with the argument `Send` after you are done sending.